# Ubuntu machine not responding to ping from Windows machine on same network

Tags: samba, shared-folders, ping

I want to fix this because it seems the reason why I cannot share ubuntu folders with my Windows machine.

Windows 7 machine network configuration:

```
IP: 192.168.2.2
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.2.1

dns: 8.8.8.8, 4.4.4.4
```

Ubuntu machine network configuration:

```
IP: 192.168.2.3
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.2.1

dns: 8.8.8.8, 4.4.4.4
```

I can ping my Windows machine from Ubuntu but I cannot ping my Ubuntu machine from Windows.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you pinging by hostname or by IP?  What is the exact error when you try to ping?

Comment: Can you post the result of the following command : iptables -L ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe your iptables (aka Firewall) has rule for blocking ping requests.
You can check it easily by disabling the iptables with the command `sudo ufw disable`. Run the ping test again.
Enable it again with `sudo ufw enable`.

Comment: It worked like a charm. I will have to learn now how to add my windows machine to the iptables in order to reactivate the firewall. Thanks!

Comment: Can you also describe how to remove this ping block rule?

Answer (score 0):

`4.4.4.4` is not a Google DNS, Google now has established public DNS servers at `8.8.8.8`, and `8.8.4.4` can additionally be used.

Comment: No, it's a Level 3 DNS, but I've read that Level 3 DNS servers shouldn't be used.